# Как выполнить react-native команду через bash?

Tags: reactjs, bash, macos, npm, root

После команды

> npm install -g react-native-cli

Появляется знакомое сообщение о том, что прав записывать в папку node нет.

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>
> npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'

И надо делать всё под sudo root.

И вопрос: как можно задать папке node свойство, чтобы команда npm install react выполнилась в итоге?

Ибо пароль ROOT забыт. Есть скорый рецепт на сброс пароля ROOT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

146% вы решили поставить npm от рута. Пишите в поддержку ибо как в линях (грузимся с флешки chroot и готово) не получится.

И на будущее https://brew.sh/index_ru классная вещь...  и рут не нужен